# how to trim leading zeros from alphanumeric text in mysql function

Tags: mysql

What mysql functions are there (if any) to trim leading zeros from an alphanumeric text field?

Field with value "00345ABC" would need to return "345ABC".

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You are looking for the [trim() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Alright, here is your example

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM myfield) FROM table
```

Comment: ++ Specifically TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM '000345ANB095')

Comment: Is this for multiple zeros as well?

Comment: select trim(LEADING '0' FROM '00000A')+0 from dual;
Why does this output 0 instead of A ?

Comment: @AniketKapse That's for the same reason that `SELECT 'A' + 0;` outputs 0 instead of 'A'. 'A' is not a number, but you're trying to add a number to it. So it converts both arguments to numbers. `A` doesn't represent a number, so it's converted to 0.
Give the MySQL documentation on Type Conversion a read.

Answer (score 18):

TIP:

If your values are purely numerical, you can also use simple casting, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE accountid = '00322994' * 1
```

will actually convert into

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE accountid = 322994
```

which is sufficient solution in many cases and also I believe is performance more effective. (warning - value type changes from STRING to INT/FLOAT).

In some situations, using some casting function might be also a way to go:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: I think `+ 0` is a more common way to cast to an int than `* 1`

Comment: This is very useful if the value is like '000000'.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to update one entire column of a table, you can use

```
USE database_name;
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field` = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM `field`) WHERE `field` LIKE '0%';
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe you'd be best off with this:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM myField)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM *columnName*) FROM *tableName* ;
```

This also work correctly

Answer (score 5):

TRIM will allow you to remove the trailing, leading or all characters. Some examples on the use of the TRIM function in MySQL:

```
select trim(myfield) from (select '   test' myfield) t;
>> 'test'
select trim('0' from myfield) from (select '000000123000' myfield) t;
>> '123'
select trim(both '0' from myfield) from (select '000000123000' myfield) t;
>> '123'
select trim(leading '0' from myfield) from (select '000000123000' myfield) t;
>> '123000'
select trim(trailing '0' from myfield) from (select '000000123000' myfield) t;
>> '000000123'
```

If you want to remove only a select amount of leading/trailing characters, look into the LEFT/RIGHT functions, with combination of the LEN and INSTR functions

Answer (score 4):

simply perfect:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM myfield) FROM table
```

Answer (score 4):

just remove space between `TRIM ( LEADING` 
use

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM accountid ) = '00322994'
```

Comment: AWESOME! You save my time!