# How to remove the first characters in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a column that contains string. It is a number but saved as string. The string might start with 00 or more than two zeros. I need to remove the zeros and insert the new value (after removing) into another column. The problem is the number of zeros at the beginning is not fixed. It can be 2 or more. Is this task possible to be done with MySQL ? How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good hint is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96952/how-to-trim-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text-in-mysql-function):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET column2 = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM column1)
```

supposing that the original value is stored in `column1` and you want to write the 0-trimmed one in `column2`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CONVERT(col,UNSIGNED INTEGER)` to convert it into the number, that should remove the leading zeros.

query can be

```
insert into <table> values(select CONVERT(col,UNSIGNED INTEGER),..... from <table2>);
```

Comment: There is no way I convert the number. It is very long.