# Find all integers in a varchar column of a Mysql Database

Tags: mysql

This is going to sound odd... but I need a way to figure out all entries in a specific column that are stored as integers.

Apparently in the past someone converted this column from integer to varchar without MySQL strict mode turned on, and this apparently resulted in a few entries that were left as integers:

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM inv_array where serial = 187870123
```

Doesn't Work:

```
SELECT * FROM inv_array where serial = '187870123'
```

the serial column is configured as a varchar, so the above should have worked, no? Shouldn't MySQL cast these integers as a varchar? Am I going crazy?

I need to find all the entries in this database where serial is being stored as integer and convert them to varchar.

Comment: a column cannot have mixed types. either they're all integers, or they're all varchars. you cannot have a mishmash of both in there.

Comment: @Chris in the case zerofill (e.g. the column was set to `serial int(20) zerofill`) is the problem this how you can remove them in for example a select query. `SELECT trim(leading 0 FORM serial) FROM inv_array WHERE serial = 187870124`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you have an issue with your data.  Assuming the data is stored as a `VARCHAR`, then the reason the above is working in your first query and not in your second query is because MySQL tries to convert the data in the `VARCHAR` field to an integer to compare with your first query.  It will take the all the first non-alpha characters to compare the integer against.

This will actually be easier to show you.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6c75/1).

If you have data in your VARCHAR field such as line breaks, then the first query works because it matches up until the line break.  Same way, if your data was 123XYZ and you compared that to 123, it would be returned.  That's because MySQL converts 123XYZ to 123 when searching by an integer value.

```
CREATE TABLE inv_array  (id int, serial varchar(100));
INSERT INTO inv_array VALUES (1, '123XYZ
                                 ');
SELECT * FROM inv_array where serial = 123; #returns records
SELECT * FROM inv_array where serial = '123XYZ'; #does not return any records
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: If that were true, wouldn't this query work?

SELECT * FROM inv_array where serial LIKE '187870123%';

It's not working in this database.

Comment: Not if there is space at the beginning.  Try SELECT * FROM inv_array where serial LIKE '%187870123%';

Comment: That was it. 

It showed up with LIKE '%187870123%' but not with the REGEXP statements from Pascal below... how can I figure out what's in this thing?

Comment: @Chris if you want to know the current column types you can always could use `SHOW COLUMNS FORM inv_array` to see how the column is set. Everything inside the fields was set to the current format when the column type was changed.

Comment: I know the current column types, it seems that these serials have leading zeroes to them and that's why they're not showing up.

Comment: @Chris the problem might be with zerofill. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96952/how-to-trim-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text-in-mysql-function

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some spaces in some rows.

You can find such rows with a regexp like so:

number with leading spaces

```
select * from inv_array where serial REGEXP ' +[0-9]+'
```

number with trailing spaces

```
select * from inv_array where serial REGEXP '[0-9]+ +'
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are all VARCHAR and you want to search for INT you could use CAST to do this without any major changes to the your database.

VARCHAR TO INT

```
SELECT * FROM inv_array WHERE CAST(SERIAL_VARCHAR AS UNSIGNED) = 187870124;
```

INT TO VARCHAR

```
SELECT * FROM inv_array_1 WHERE CAST(SERIAL_INT AS CHAR) = '187870124';
```

For a permanent solution I would recommend an update of your table.

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a386/1)

In the case you do have leading zero this how you could remove them in a select query.
`SELECT trim(leading 0 FORM serial) FROM inv_array WHERE serial = 187870124`.