# MySQL SELECT with LIKE, Wildcards and leading zeroes

Tags: php, mysql, select, search, sql-like

I have a kind of odd problem. I am programming a controlpanel for a company internal application, that utilizes a MySQL database in the backend.

I currently have a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ldap_user LIKE '%--Searchterm--%' OR Firstname LIKE '%--Searchterm--%' OR Lastname LIKE '%--Searchterm--%' OR id LIKE '%--Searchterm--%';
```

Where "--Searchterm--" is i provide it via PHP. Now i want to be able to hand over a searchterm with leading zeroes and still be able to match it to the unpadded ids.

I know, that i could strip the zeroes with PHP, but i want a pure MySQL-solution if possible.

I have no clue what to look for, because everything i find does not address a Select-query while "searching" other fields than the id as well.

If possible i prefer a query, that does not use some wild JOINs, but plain MySQL.

Comment: Not quite understand it, you mean while query searches the data the returned data should be free from zeros ? Can you show some sample data in the database and sample input for search ?

Comment: is searchterm always going to be numbers? If not, then you can't use the simple trick of `WHERE ... LIKE CONCAT('%', searchterm + 0, '%')`, because that's muck up any actual search STRINGS you pass in.

Comment: You mean searching for inverted variant like: " '--Searchterm--0000000' LIKE ldap_user" and ldap_user has value of '%--Searchterm--%'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96952/how-to-trim-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-text-in-mysql-function

Comment: Xendo - [you should answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mattt!

The solution was to use

```
[...] OR id LIKE TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM '--Searchterm--');
```

-> *Facepalm*

I have not though of TRIM, and did not know, you could simply use it this way.

Thanks again!