# How can I delete extra zero in a number in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example,I input the number,it will input the format number.

```
if I input 0010,it return 10;
if I input 0.0200,it return 0.02;
if I input 0.10,it return 0.1;
```

I try to use this code,but it do not work.Can I defined a function or a stored procedure to encapsulate this business functionality?

```
select rtrim(00.40)
```

Comment: You "input" a number? What does that mean? 0010 *is* 10 and 0.0200 *is* 0.02. Most GUI tools show the simplest version of a number when selecting it, so you get exactly what you want. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/56241 . What do you get instead? And you can always format a number to a string with `FORMAT`; see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: Yes,I mean select number.

Comment: use `trim()+0`, see below ;)

Comment: So `select 0010` doesn't return 10 in your system?

Comment: What "extra" zero are you referring to? Also, your sample code is not using strings, which means there is nothing to remove - _a number is what it is, nothing more nothing less_. When you compare `0010` and `10` they are the same.

Comment: Many questions about mysql and trimming: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+trim And more specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/q/96952/224704

Answer (score 0):

use **trim()** functionality with **both** option, refer [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

**Updated:**
You might want to refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968531/remove-trailing-zeros-in-decimal-value-with-changing-length), gives you a lot more details

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM() + 0` can do the trick:

```
select trim(0010)+0, trim(0.0200)+0, trim(0.10)+0 from dual
```

output:

```
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| trim(0010)+0 | trim(0.0200)+0 | trim(0.10)+0 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
|           10 |           0.02 |          0.1 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: How exactly is this any better than `SELECT 0010, 0.0200, 0.10`?

Comment: if there are any whitespaces (because of user input), the output will be different. otherwhise yes, there is no difference.

Comment: You're missing the point ... you (and OP) are using ***numbers*** - not strings. You can put as much white-space around a number as you like, you won't change it. E.g. `SELECT   0010   ,    0.0200   ,    0.10    ` _Side note: Until OP can figure out what he/she wants to ask, the question is unclear and should be closed. At best it's a duplicate. Your answer (and almost any answer) just adds to the nonsense._

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM Youvalue)
FROM ...
```

ex.

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM '0.0200')
    FROM dual
```

Refer this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: `select trim(trailing '0' from 0010)` will return 1 or 001 (if using single quotes) but not 10.

Comment: @mitkosoft now check it

Comment: For floats yes, but for 0010 you must use LEADING option